# How could I fix Google analytics WP plugin error 23?

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is anyone faced the following error? How could I fix this up? Thank you in advance for your recommendations

`Error Details
Count: 1
Last Error:
2020-08-09 11:37:48: Deconfin_Service_Exception: Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A185858750&start-date=today&end-date=today&metrics=ga%3Ausers&dimensions=ga%3Ahour&quotaUser=u1s1p185858750&samplingLevel=HIGHER_PRECISION: (503) There was a temporary error. Please try again later. in /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/tools/src/Deconfin/Http/REST.php:110`

Stack trace:
#0 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/tools/src/Deconfin/Http/REST.php(62): Deconfin_Http_REST::decodeHttpResponse(Object(Deconfin_Http_Request), Object(Deconfin_Client))

#1 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/tools/src/Deconfin/Task/Runner.php(174): Deconfin_Http_REST::doExecute(Object(Deconfin_Client), Object(Deconfin_Http_Request))

#2 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/tools/src/Deconfin/Http/REST.php(46): Deconfin_Task_Runner->run()

#3 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/tools/src/Deconfin/Client.php(611): Deconfin_Http_REST::execute(Object(Deconfin_Client), Object(Deconfin_Http_Request))

#4 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/tools/src/Deconfin/Service/Resource.php(240): Deconfin_Client->execute(Object(Deconfin_Http_Request))

#5 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/tools/src/Deconfin/Service/Analytics.php(2052): Deconfin_Service_Resource->call('get', Array, 'Deconfin_Servic...')

#6 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/tools/gapi.php(361): Deconfin_Service_Analytics_DataGa_Resource->get('ga:185858750', 'today', 'today', 'ga:users', Array)

#7 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/tools/gapi.php(457): GAINWP_GAPI_Controller->handle_corereports('185858750', 'today', 'today', 'ga:users', Array, 'qr2_3095809337')

#8 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/tools/gapi.php(950): GAINWP_GAPI_Controller->get_areachart_data('185858750', 'today', 'today', 'users', false)

#9 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ga-in/admin/ajax-actions.php(116): GAINWP_GAPI_Controller->get('185858750', 'users', 'today', 'today', false, 'sessions')

#10 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(288): GAINWP_Backend_Ajax->ajax_item_reports('')

#11 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(312): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
#12 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(478): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
#13 /home/u462343431/public_html/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php(175): do_action('wp_ajax_gainwp_...')
#14 {main}

GAPI Error:
Array
(
[0] => 503
[1] => Array
(
[0] => Array
(
[message] => There was a temporary error. Please try again later.
[domain] => global
[reason] => backendError
)

```
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s a temporary error issued by Google. It’s not closely related to plugin, it’s from Google’s API having a temporary outage.

This Google Analytics API error indicates that there was a problem processing your query request. This can occur if you make too many bad queries in a short period of time, or if you use up your quota for the day. In some cases, it may indicate that the server was too busy to process your request (usually for a very large query).

Too many attempts will cause even good queries to get blocked in this way.

The only solution is to wait for a period of time (next day) until the API lets you try again.

Comment: Today everything got back to normal. Thank you for your prompt reply!